# MySQL "fill up" missing values in histogram

Tags: mysql, sql, histogram

Using SQL, I want to create a kind of histogram. The data itself is already organized in a way, that makes creating the histogram easy and straight forward. The simplified query basically looks like:

```
SELECT rank, COUNT(*) AS count FROM ranks GROUP BY rank ORDER BY rank;
```

Which gives me a table like the following:

```
+------+-------+
| rank | count |
+------+-------+
| 0    | 20    |
| 1    | 15    |
| 2    | 9     |
| 6    | 3     |
| 9    | 2     |
+------+-------+
```

The problem: For further processing of the data, I require the zero-bins to be given explicitly. In this case (knowing that my ranks go from 0 to 9), I need a table with ten rows (e.g. rank 3, 4, 5, 7 and 8 would have a count 0 explicitly stated in the table).

I thought about creating a temporary table with the ranks as values and joining my query to that table, but that does not seem particularly elegant. Is there a nicer way? (avoiding complicated procedures).

Comment: nope. there is no "elegant" way for this. sql dbs cannot generate data out of thin air. if you have nothing for a particular group, then you'll get nothing back for it.

Comment: Are there any tables that relate to the ranks table?  Your prose does mention zero bins.  What's that all about?

Comment: @DanBracuk In the original database, the query is more complicated and the result is joined from multiple tables. The use case, shortly described: I have a annotated dataset with relevant/non relevant items and I want to create statistics, how many relevant items are found on a specific rank. As I have to perform multiple of such queries and transfer the results to another application for further processing, having the zero-bins listed would make my life considerably easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, just be sure to change the reference to anyTable, to any table that contains more rows than the number of ranks you wish to generate.

It still uses a join, but avoids the need for a temp table.

Regards,

James

```
CREATE TABLE ranks
SELECT 0 rank, 20 count
    UNION ALL
SELECT 1 rank, 15 count
    UNION ALL
SELECT 2 rank, 9 count
    UNION ALL
SELECT 6 rank, 3 count
    UNION ALL
SELECT 9 rank, 2 count;

SET @VCounter := -1;

SELECT A.rank, B.count FROM
    (SELECT @VCounter := @VCounter + 1 rank FROM anyTable WHERE @VCounter < 10) A
LEFT JOIN
    ranks B
ON A.rank = B.rank
ORDER BY A.rank;
```

Let me know if you have any issues with implementation,

Regards,

James

Comment: +1 but the anyTable should have more than 10 records

Comment: @StanislavL, Your right, this is a weakness regarding this approach which I posted about earlier today, I'll update my answer here if I come up with anything better.